# TWRP 3.0.0.0 Failed to Restore Correctly

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, twrp, nexus

I backed up my Nexus 9 and then did a CyanogenMod update, which then lead to me not being able to use WiFi. So I went back to TWRP and restored my backup which was 5GB. It consisted of my apps and games nothing major – but once I rebooted I had no apps or Gapps was like a did a hard reset. So I went and restored a even older backup which I call my baseline backup which is consists of a fresh CM13 and Gapps install, so I had to start over none the less and redownload everything.

Any ideas what went bad? I'm kinda scared to rely on TWRP backup now or to even update CM.

Comment: From what I've found with TWRP, it does not backup any apps but the ones in /system (system apps).

Comment: @Qiangong2 TWRP doesn't backup apps, but partitions. So if the backup covers `/system` and `/data`, it covers all apps (system apps as well as user apps). By default, these two partitions are included in a TWRP backup – and you have the option to include others, de-select one of the two, or make your own selection at all.

Comment: I backed up System and Data

Comment: @user1871 Did you check whether you had enough space, *before* starting the backup?

Comment: yes i had 20 free gb